# Why the below PHP cURL code is not POSTing any data?

Tags: php, curl, web-scraping

Can anybody please tell what i am doing wrong in below code ?

I am working on php script to login and scrape data from https://beams.us.yazaki.com/BEAMSLogin/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2FBeams%2FDefault.aspx

I have tried with Below curl code.

```
<?php
define('USERNAME', 'XXX');
define('PASSWORD', 'XXX');
define('DOMAIN', 'XXX');
define('USER_AGENT', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.2309.372 Safari/537.36');
define('COOKIE_FILE', 'cookie.txt');
define('LOGIN_FORM_URL', 'https://beams.us.yazaki.com/BEAMSLogin/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fBeams%2fDefault.aspx');
define('LOGIN_ACTION_URL', 'https://beams.us.yazaki.com/BEAMSLogin/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fBeams%2fDefault.aspx');
$postValues = array(
    'txtUserName' => USERNAME,
    'txtPassword' => PASSWORD,
    'lstDomain'   => DOMAIN
);
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, LOGIN_ACTION_URL);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($postValues));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, COOKIE_FILE);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, USER_AGENT);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, LOGIN_FORM_URL);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);
curl_exec($curl);
if(curl_errno($curl)){
    throw new Exception(curl_error($curl));
}
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://beams.us.yazaki.com/BEAMS/SearchAndResults.aspx?topic=component');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, COOKIE_FILE);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, USER_AGENT);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
echo curl_exec($curl);
?>
```

I am getting the output like below page.

```
Object not found!

The requested URL was not found on this server. The link on the referring page seems to be wrong or outdated. Please inform the author of that page about the error. 

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster. 

Error 404

localhost
Apache/2.4.43 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1g PHP/7.4.8 *
```

And the browser is getting redirected to http://localhost/BeamsLogin/AuthenticationSelect.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fBEAMS%2fSearchAndResults.aspx%3ftopic%3dcomponent&topic=component

I am earnestly waiting for response.

Thanks.

EDIT 1
@Shibon
I think this website doesn't use any csrf token. I am giving HTTP header live content. Please check once.

```
https://beams.us.yazaki.com/BEAMSLogin/Login.aspx?ReturnURL=%2fBeams%2fDefault.aspx
Host: beams.us.yazaki.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:60.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/60.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Referer: https://beams.us.yazaki.com/
Connection: keep-alive
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1

GET: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Encoding: gzip
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Tue, 15 Sep 2020 06:19:19 GMT
Content-Length: 3376
```

Comment: I think is something related to the cookies. Try first to fetch the website and then trying to login and also you should review the __VIEWSTATE in the form.

Comment: I tried to fetch with   ```$cookies = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_COOKIELIST);
print_r($cookies);``` and i got Array() as output. I think you are correct. Can you please suggest how to work this out as i am a bit new to this.

Comment: Thanks @nguaman, I was supposed to send __VIEWSTATE, __EVENTVALIDATION, __VIEWSTATEGENERATOR along with username and password.

Answer (score 0):

Try the bellow code

```
$ch= curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "-"); //to set session and cookie for the current $ch object
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, LOGIN_ACTION_URL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($postValues));
$resp = curl_exec($ch);
if(!$resp) {
   print_r(curl_error($ch));
   exit;
}
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://beams.us.yazaki.com/BEAMS/SearchAndResults.aspx?topic=component');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
echo curl_exec($ch);
```

In this have set cookie initially and the used that in all request

Comment: Thanks@Shibon, I tried this. But the same error. Basically, I dont know why the browser is getting redirected to [Link](http://localhost/BeamsLogin/AuthenticationSelect.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fBEAMS%2fSearchAndResults.aspx%3ftopic%3dcomponent&topic=component). This link is nowhere mentioned in source page of login form.

Comment: Can you please try with out return url like this https://beams.us.yazaki.com/BEAMSLogin/Login.aspx

Comment: No; still it is getting redirected to same (Authentication.aspx) page. And basically it is searching this link on my localhost server. Earlier i tried with simple HTML dom parser by which I am able to send form data but unable to press login button, which now i know; of no use. One more thing; source page of this form has action link like (./Login.aspx). So how can i make this redirected to the same https address and not on my localhost ? I think this is issue.

Comment: So your first curl is success but it is redirecting is it..

Comment: yes. I am getting form visible but instead of directing the link to component search after login; i am getting directed to some link which is nowhere mentioned on source and I don't know whether POST has sent any data and my login is successful.

Comment: So your login is not success .. Check whether any csrf token is there to login

Comment: I have updated the question as per your comment. Please check once.